# Android Studio Live-Edit feature error: multiple minApi detected

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to enable Android Studio Preview Live-Edit feature for Jetpack Compose. But it fails updating the UI with message saying that:
Live-edit post-processing failure: Multiple MinAPI detected

I wasn't able to find any docs on the Android dev site. And the docs button gives a 404 :)

Anyway, maybe someone was able to figure out what does that mean and what is a MinAPI?

Here is a screenshot from Studio with that error:
[image: Screenshot]

Here is my root build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.0-beta04' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.0-beta04' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
}
```

And here is my module build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk{
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
        }

        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
        viewBinding true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.4'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'

    //And some other dependencies specific to the project
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a known issue over at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/283737440.

Comment: A fix should be available for 8.2 Canary 8, scheduled for release today (June 13) and 8.1 RC 1, scheduled for release on June 20.